# Unable to install node.js on windows 32-bit OS

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to install node.js on windows 32-bit OS while installing, a situation comes where it perfoms "Rolling back Action" nd eventually installation stops can plz anyone help me

Comment: have you downloaded proper package of node.js for win 32 ?

Comment: yes complete package i hv downloaded..

Comment: Try installation from both .exe and .msi setup files.I got the same issue try from both with logged as administrator previlage.

Comment: i hv downloaded .exe file A console opens den wt next step should i take? plz help me

Comment: in next step you ave accept the aggrement?

Comment: it simply shows the console window

Comment: to check node.js installed or not please got to command prompt and type node,